# Alert Dialog Validation in android

Tags: android

When i click the save button without entering values the dialog gets disappear.I want to show the dialog box as well as want to do the validation.Please help me if anybody knows.

Here is my code:

```
 TextView tvUserName=new TextView(this);
            TextView tvPassword=new TextView(this);
            TextView tvURL=new TextView(this);
            final EditText etUserName=new EditText(this); 
            final EditText etPassword=new EditText(this);
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
            LinearLayout login= new LinearLayout(this);
            login.setOrientation(1); //1 is for vertical orientation
            tvUserName.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.username));
            tvPassword.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.password));
            login.addView(tvURL);
            login.addView(etURL);
            login.addView(tvUserName);
            login.addView(etUserName);
            login.addView(tvPassword);
            etPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            login.addView(etPassword);
            alert.setView(login);
            alert.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.login));
            alert.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.login), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {             
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {   
                    strUserName=etUserName.getText().toString();
                    XmlUtil.username=strUserName;
                    strPassword=etPassword.getText().toString();
                    strhwdXml=etURL.getText().toString();
                    if((strUserName.length()==0)||(strPassword.length()==0){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please enter username and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Comment: add your code here for dialog...

Comment: You might be calling dialog.dismiss() in a wrong place.. posting your code would help...

Comment: add your code how you are creating dialog

Comment: Sorry! Please ignore save button in the above text i entered. instead it is login button.

Comment: You can use my answer [here][1]. This might solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391133/how-to-validate-string-entered-by-user-using-alertdialog

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363209/alertdialog-with-positive-button-and-validating-custom-edittext

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void showAlertBox() {
        AlertDialog alertBox = null;
        alertBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertBox.setTitle("titleText");
        alertBox.setMessage("messageText");
        alertBox.setCancelable(false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View alert_webview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null);
        alertBox.setView(alert_webview);
        btnfromlayout = (Button) alert_webview.findViewById(R.id.btnclose);
        btnfromlayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Whatever you want on click...compare
                // if(strUserName.equalsIgnoreCase("") ||
                // strPassword.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                // Your toast msg
                // }else{
                // cAlert.dismiss();
                // }
                Log.i("Close", "Close");
            }
        });

        alertBox.show();
    }


@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int vId = v.getId();
        switch (vId) {
        case R.id.btnclose:
            //Whatever you want on click...compare
//if(strUserName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || strPassword.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//Your toast msg
//}else{
//          cAlert.dismiss();
//}
            Log.i("Close", "Close");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

### R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtcustmessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Txt custom Layout For Alert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnclose"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Close Custom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

/// Like the above layout u can create your own layout for login controls with design
and set click listners as per the layout and required action

Comment: How can we cast alertBox as button here?

Comment: check it once i hve changed...as i forget to cast button from inflated view...so check it once

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make that kind of AlertDialog, would be to make a new custom layout for it, just like you would make for an activity. If you're using setPositiveButton etc. they close the dialog on default, when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

better to include button also instead of using setpositivebutton. if yo have button then you can do as you want.