# How to 'cancel' a button press?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am currently trying to work with AlertDialogs.

Currently, I have an EditText in my AlertDialog, and want to restrict the input to only Integers. I have used a basic try and catch block to avoid the app crashing form a NumberFormatException.

However, I want to set it up so that when the user tries to press the button with the incorrect input, the input does not register and the Dialog is not cancelled.

```
UpperLimitDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Positive_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        int RawInput = settings.getInt("UpperLimit", 12);
                        try {
                            RawInput = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                        }catch (NumberFormatException se) {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsMenu.this, "Non-Integer Value, No Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Here I want the app to not register the click and prevent the dialog box from closing.
                        }
                        editor.putInt("UpperLimit", RawInput);
                        editor.apply();
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsMenu.this, "Set Upper Limit to " + RawInput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

What method can I use to achieve this?

Comment: why dont use use xml input type as a number so you dont need to check for a string value

Comment: I thought I could just scrape it without using a custom XML. But I guess not, better switch back to using XMLs then.

Comment: its up to you.if you want you can try Linos answer and keep the alert dialog as it is till its a number input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic trick here is to use the dialog's `setCancelable` to `false` and call `dismiss()` only when the input has been validated.

More info here: [AlertDialog with positive button and validating custom EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363209/alertdialog-with-positive-button-and-validating-custom-edittext)

Answer (score 2):

Use can acheive `input to only Integers` this by both Java or XML.

> Java

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

> XML

```
android:inputType = "numberSigned"
```

this may helps you in both way.

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict user to allow only number then you can simply try with-

> android:inputType="number"

and if you want to allow with floating number then try with-

> android:inputType="numberDecimal"

and in any case if you want to disable dialog button then try this-

```
Button theButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
theButton.setEnabled(false);
```

will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use in EditText's xml code:

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

This will let user input only integers. Hope this helps!