# Validate an EditText in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to validate an `TextInputLayout` in an `AlertDialog.Builder`. Pls help me. I've tried to validate it in a simple way but when the positive button is pressed, nothing happens.

Thanks

```
    private TextInputLayout txtUpdateWeight;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.MyDialogTheme);

    final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_update_weight_dialog, null);

    txtUpdateWeight = view.findViewById(R.id.tlUpdateWeight);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Update Weight")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if (!validateField()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    String etWeight = txtUpdateWeight.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                    DatabaseReference myDB = db.getReference().child("Additional details");
                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();

                    updates.put("weight", etWeight);

                    myDB.updateChildren(updates);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Weight updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

This is my validation function

```
public boolean validateField() {
    String etWeight = txtUpdateWeight.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if (etWeight.isEmpty()) {
        txtUpdateWeight.setError("Enter your weight");
        return false;
    } else {
        txtUpdateWeight.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you debug??

Comment: Hello, after a deep research i've found an answer at that link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363209/alertdialog-with-positive-button-and-validating-custom-edittext/11363525

Thanks to help

Answer (score 4):

You should use [**`TextUtils`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils)

```
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etWeight))
```

**Note**

You should use **`TextInputEditText`** instead of **TextInputLayout**.

I assume your XML is

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/your_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Then

```
 String etWeight = textInputEditTextOBJ.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: i think so it is same as he is doing.

Comment: @AliAhmed I think the user should use TextInputEditText .

Comment: No using `TextUtils` didn't solve the problem. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Yes. just saw that,, he is doing wrong. He should use TextInputEditText, No TextInputLayout

Comment: @OoMaRjOhUr you should take value from `TextInputEditText`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the error message did shown up but the dialog disappeared immediately after the positive button is clicked

Comment: @OoMaRjOhUr use `else` block `if (!validateField()) {
                        return;
                    } else{   }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, it still closes.

Comment: @OoMaRjOhUr kindly debug your app.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya even after debugging nothing happens the dialog closes instantly without validating the field

Comment: Hello, after a deep research i've found an answer at that link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363209/alertdialog-with-positive-button-and-validating-custom-edittext/11363525

Thanks to help

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
public boolean validateField() {
String etWeight = txtUpdateWeight.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etWeight)) {
    txtUpdateWeight.setError("Enter your weight");
    return false;
} else {
    txtUpdateWeight.setError(null);
    return true;
}}
```

**Add else also**

```
   if (!validateField()) {
                        return;
                    }else{
                    String etWeight = txtUpdateWeight.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                    DatabaseReference myDB = db.getReference().child("Additional details");
                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();

                    updates.put("weight", etWeight);

                    myDB.updateChildren(updates);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Weight updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: No, it does not validate the field and closes instantly

Comment: Hello, after a deep research i've found an answer at that link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363209/alertdialog-with-positive-button-and-validating-custom-edittext/11363525

Thanks to help